# Name each new dir with the next available number with php

Tags: php

I'm working on a php file where I want to create one or more directories with names ranging from 1 to 999 or more. I'm creating the first of all directories using the following code:

```
<?php
$id = '001';
mkdir($id)
?>
```

What I want to succeed is to automatically create a new directory using as a name the next available number (i.e. 002, 003, 004, 005 etc) either as a string or an integer. However, I really stuck and I try to use:

```
<?php
$id = 001;
if (file_exists($id)) {
$id = $id + 1;
mkdir($id);
}
?>
```

..but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I forgot to mention that the above code is part of the if statement inside the same php code.

Comment: First of all, i would recommend you to use DB for storing that, more performant and easy to maintain... What is it giving you ? What error ?

Comment: @P0lT10n it doesn't give any kind of a particular error. It provides the comment inside die('Unable to make folder') because the dirname is already exist and it is unable to do the calculation to make the new dir with the next available number.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, depending on your use case. This function may work for you:

```
<?PHP
function makedir($id){
  if(file_exists($id)){
    $id++;
    makedir($id);
  }else{
    mkdir($id);
    return true;
  }
}

makedir(1);
```

This solution of incremented directory names is going to become ugly after a while though; you should probably find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: code is working, but, how do you make the $id dir subfolder? For example, a/b/c/d/$id ...

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
// Loop through all numbers.
for ($i = 1; $i <= 999; $i++) {
    // Get the formatted dir name (prepending 0s)
    $dir = sprintf('%03d', $i);
    // If the dir doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Edit: the above was assuming you wanted to make all 999 directories. You could do the following to just append the next available number:

```
function createDir($dir) {
    $newDir = $dir;
    $num = 1;
    while (file_exists($newDir)) {
        $newDir = $dir.sprintf('%03d', $num++);
    }
    return $newDir;
}
```